# MariaDB Python database always returns empty

Tags: python, sql, mariadb

Trying to learn some simple python/mariadb integration, and ran this script to add test values into a test database....

```
import mysql.connector as mariadb

mariadb_connection = mariadb.connect(user='root', password='password', database='testDatabase', host='localhost')
create_cursor = mariadb_connection.cursor()

create_cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO testtable (COLUMN1) VALUES ('HI')""")
```

So far so good, this is where the error comes up:

```
create_cursor.execute("""SELECT * from testtable""")
result = create_cursor.fetchall()
print(result)
```

Now when I run this code, it returns "[ ]", leading me to suspect this table is somehow empty- however, the insertion code threw no errors, and is perfectly in line with several online tutorials I found. Quite confused on this one (my apologies if this is a blatantly obvious problem- I am new to SQL).

Comment: Do you ever call `mariadb_connection.commit()`?

Comment: I thought .execute() had the same function?

Comment: Well, you thought wrong. Execute runs a query, but you do need to commit the transaction too.

Comment: Or use [`autocommit` property](https://mariadb.com/docs/reference/conpy/api/autocommit/).